# woocommerce add-to-cart empty

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

I got the problem that when I click add-to-cart as guest customer, the cart always says empty

but it's all fine with when I'm login as admin

My server using varnish , nginx, php-fpm
and I add varnish conf and nginx conf for woocommerce to not cache

and I also has change the session.save_path to /tmp and set the permission to 777

but all of this doesn't work

my boss told me to get shop on-line in two weeks, I've been working with this issue for total 1 week,

what should I do, or something I need to check???

I think the problem will be the cache or the session

here's my site: http://i-health.cc/shop

Answer (score 2):

I know its old but I fixed this issue by simply disabling 'Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives on the' on the settings >> Products tab. Not elegant as it would be nice for the AJAX to work but dont have the time to dig around. Hope its of help to soemone out there.

Answer (score 1):

in your server config file look for

```
location / {

    $uri $uri/ /index.php
```

it may be a little different depending on your server config but you should have a line with `index.php` Just add `?$args` after `index.php`

```
$uri $uri/ /index.php
```

should look like this

```
$uri $uri/ /index.php?$args
```

Don't forget to restart nginx. This should fix the empty cart issue.